# How to prove this set has volume 0?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $A \subset \mathbb R^n$ be an open set and the function $g: A\to \mathbb R^n$ be a $C^1$ function. Let

$$B=\{x\in A: Jg(x)=0\}$$ ($Jg$ means the Jacobian of $g$), then $g(B)$ is of volume zero. (just the volume cover by cubes).

Comment: Do you know [Sard's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sard's_theorem)?

Comment: @julien  Is there anyway to prove this without this theorem?

Comment: Well, this is essentially this theorem. I dont't think that the fact that the domain and the codomain have the same dimension would make it significantly easier.